Please Help Needed! Loose/Sunken Outlet Box

Need help or a solution how do we go about fixing a loose and sunken
outlet box.
This also did not have a ground connected previously. We fixed the
ground issue by installing a GFCI outlet as this was the upstream
outlet. Please verify if this is the way.



@crip659, This outlet is inside, in a bedroom.
Edit: I'm new here, how do I post more pictures?

I am hoping the edit button will allow more pictures.  How the box is installed in the wall is the most important.  GFCIs should be on the first outlet on the circuit, all the ones after the first should be protected also.

I'll try to figure out how to add more pictures.
Yes, this is the first outlet in the circuit.

Under the Edit function, look for the Mountain icon, that's where pictures can be posted.

@crip659 Why would you use a weatherproof box indoors?

@barnbowling you need to edit your question to add more pics (I the same way you added the 1st one). You can't add more pics down here in the comments.

How about showing us a pic of the actual loose/sunken box?
